# connection to sql server via keyvault

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm working with a powershell script that I need to connect to SSISDB database via keyvault but getting error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user ''."
```

Here is the connection string I'm using in code:

```
$env        = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'Env'
$vaultName  = 'ab-'+$env.ToLower()+'-bi-keyvault'
$dataSource = 'ab'+$env.ToLower()+'dbserver01.database.windows.net'
Write-Output "vaultName: " $vaultName

$password = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name 'DBPassword' 
$userName = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name 'DBUsername' 
$passwordSecret = $password.SecretValueText    
$userNameSecret = $userName.SecretValueText


##########################################################

Write-Output "SSISDB"
Write-Output "JOB START"
# Create connection to Master DB
$database   = 'SSISDB'
Write-Output "Running job on " $database

$MasterDatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$MasterDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=False;User ID=$userNameSecret ;Password=$passwordSecret ;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
```

If I check connection with using userid/password directly in code , it does work but not with keyvault. Do you have any idea that what is the issue with my code?

Comment: When you write out the connection string does it look correct?

Comment: I'm totally new in powershell, don't know how to check the connection string.

Comment: Use `write-output` just like you're already doing.

Comment: Got this as result: Data Source=abtestdbserver01.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID= ;Password= ;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False

Comment: Looks like `$passwordSecret` and `$userNameSecret` are blank or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` doesn't return the value of the secret object by default.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-5.4.0#example-5--get-the-plain-text-value-of-the-current-version-of-a-specific-secret), you should use:

```
$passwordSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name 'DBPassword' -AsPlainText
$userNameSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name 'DBUsername' -AsPlainText
```

I have no idea why `SecretValueText` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! changed the code and now can connect with keyvault.